# Rating System in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, architecture

If we look at the stackoverflow website we have votes. But the question is what is the bestway to store who has voted and who has not. Lets also simplify this even more and say that we can only vote Up, and we can only Remove the Up vote.

I was thinking having the table to be in such form

> `question - Id(INT) | userId(INT) | title(TEXT) | vote(INT) | ratedBy(TEXT)`

Thre rest is self explanitory but ratedBy is a Comma Seperated Id values of the Users.

I was thinking to read the **ratedBy** and compare it with the **userId** of the current logged in User. If he dosent exist in the **ratedBy** he can vote Up, otherwise he can remove his vote. Which in turn will remove the value from **ratedBy**

Comment: If this has been discussed before, redirect me plz :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think to make another table "vote" is better. The relationship between users and votes is n to n, therefore a new table should be created. It should be something like this:

```
question id (int) | user id (int) | permanent (bool) | timestamp (datetime)
```

Permanent field can be used to make votes stay after a given time, as SO does.
Other fields may be added according to desired features.
As each row will take at least 16B, you can have up to 250M rows in the table before the table uses 4GB (fat32 limit if there is one archive per table, which is the case for MyISAM and InnoDB).
Also, as Matthew Scharley points out in a comment, don't load all votes at once into memory (as fetching all the table in a resultset). You can always use LIMIT clause to narrow your query results.

Comment: But this leaves the question, thats a very large table over time

Comment: And? I've worked with multi-million record (logging) tables before. As long as your table is *well-designed* (reads: indexed, unlike that logging table was at first... Uggh.) it won't be (too) slow.

Comment: cool, just confirming. Il index the userId and questionId, and make them both Primary Keys. This way i think i can avoid the check :D

Comment: The other potential pitfall is, don't try to fetch the whole table at once! Loading millions of rows into memory will probably kill something in the chain somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

A new table:

Article ID | User ID | Rating

Where Article ID and User ID make up the composite key, and rating would be 1, indicating upvote, -1 for a downvote and 0 for a removed vote (or just remove the row).

Answer (score 1):

I believe your design won't be able to scale for large numbers of voters.
The typical thing to do is to create to tables

Table 1: question - Id(INT) | userId(INT) | title(TEXT) 
Table 2:  question - ID(INT) | vote(INT) | ratedBy(TEXT)

Then you can count the votes with a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.question_Id, t1.userId, t1.title, t2.sum(vote)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.question_id = t2.question_id
```

Comment: Would you say that creating two tables to link the votes will always be faster than text prcessing?

Comment: My experience so far, primarily with mysql and oracle, is that databases are better at handling tables and joins. In addition, you can add indexes which will allow you to both have faster aggregation (get the sum of the votes) and check weather a user has already voted for a certain question. The database checks the index and goes directly to the appropriate row or rows without taking into account the rest of the data. However, you should keep in mind that in order to see any differences between the two approaches you need large numbers of votes per question ( a few thousands and more).