# How to store ratings in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rating System in PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187365/rating-system-in-php-and-mysql)

I am working on a rating system on a scale from 1 to 10.  I want to be able to keep track of all users ratings and if they have already rated that particular item.

Notes:
-I have a log in so every user has a unique id in the database. 
-Each particular item also has a unique id.

My question is: How should I store this information accurately in a database in the best possible manner.

This is how I am thinking of doing it:

```
Unique_Key | Item_ID | User_ID | User_rating
     1          1           1           (1-10)
     2          1           2           (1-10)
     3          2           2           (1-10)
     4          3           1           (1-10)
     5          4           1           (1-10)
```

So if the Item_ID a user is rating is already in the db with their User_ID they wont be able to rate, otherwise they can.

I am looking for suggestions if this is a safe, clean way to do this before I start any coding.  Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a unique key to your `itemID` - `userID` combination then this will be a save method to store that information.

You can add a unique key like this

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD UNIQUE (itemID, userID);
```

> The UNIQUE constraint uniquely identifies each record in a database table. The UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints both provide a guarantee for uniqueness for a column or set of columns.

Comment: I edited it, now do you think its good?

Comment: No, don't add another column. Tell the SQL engine that `itemID`and `userID` can only be inserted in one combination. If you define a unique key and want to insert (1,2) twice, then SQL won't let you.

Comment: Okay, do you mean check for that combination and if it exists don't allow another rate/entry else if it doesn't exist then go ahead and continue?